# How to create a awaitable connection with mysql using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm new with Node.js and I'm trying to create a async `method` with Node.js, because I need to check a row inside of my database and then decide what to do with it. So I created a file called `sql-service.js`

```
const sql = require('mysql');

var connection = sql.createConnection({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    user: 'foo',
    password: 'fooo'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        return;
    }

    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});

console.log(connection.state);

module.exports.SignUpUser = (email,password)=>{
    connection.query('select * from usuario', function(error, results, fields) {
        console.log(results);
    });
}
```

And inside of my Controller :

```
const sqlService = require('../services/sql-service');
exports.post = async(req,res,next)=>{
    const Email = req.body.Email;
    const Passw = req.body.Password;
    console.log(dateT.getdate());

    if (fluentValidation.validateEmail(Email) && fluentValidation.isValidLenght(Passw)) {
        try {
            await sqlService.SignUpUser(Email,Passw);
            //emailService.send(req.body.Email,'Nome','Bem vindo ao hanggu');
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        res.status(201).send({
            Email: "Valid " + req.body.Email,
            Password: Passw.length,
            Send: 's '//Date : dateT.getDateTime()

        });
    } else {
        res.status(500).send({
            Error: "Email invalid"
        })
    }

}
```

It does connect but the result that I got it's `undefined`, I tried

```
console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].usuario);
```

But still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what schema you select?

```
var connection = sql.createConnection ({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    user:'foo',
    password : 'fooo',
    database : 'you_db'
});
```

test